# How to code properly with MPI?

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to code with MPI, but when I compile with `gcc` I get these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qmXJ.png), which I don't how to fix.  Here is the code:

```
#include < stdio.h > 

  int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int pid, pnr;
    int A[100000];
    int B[100000];
    int v0, v1, v2;

    MPI_Init( & argc, & argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORD, & pid);
    MPI_COMM_size(MPI_COMM_WORD, & pnr);
    MPI_Status status;

    for (int i = 1; i < (100000 - 1); i++) {

      v1 = A[i - 1];
      MPI_Send( & v0, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORD);

      v2 = A[i + 1];
      MPI_Send( & v1, 2, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORD);

      v3 = 2 * A[i];
      MPI_Send( & v0, 3, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORD);

      if (pid == 0) {

        int v;

        for (int j = 1; j != pnr; i++) {
          MPI_Recv( & v, j, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0,
            MPI_COMM_WORD, & status);

          if (MPI_SUCCESS) {

            B[i] = v;
          } else {
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORD, 1);
          }

        }

      }

    }

    MPI_Finalize();

  }
```

I have tried to follow the structure of this MPI send / recv [tutorial](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/), but have obviously done something wrong.

Comment: You need to include the mpi header and you need to compile with the mpi compiler.

Comment: And you should [edit] your question to include the relevant errors in the question itself.

Comment: @Chiel: when I include the mpi header, it says `No such file or directory`

Comment: @JonnyHenly: I did, I uploaded a screenshot of the errors I get

Comment: Probably you did not install an MPI library. Install MPICH or OpenMPI.

Comment: OpenMPI is installed, but I get the same error

Comment: Install libopenmpi-dev.

Comment: 'for (int i = 1; i < (100000 - 1); i++)' range of that loop is one short of the full array, and 'v2 = A[i + 1];' is out-of-bounds when i=999999.

Comment: in the `for` loop, `i` varies between `1` and `99998` so i do not see any index overflow

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include the mpi.h and possibly stdlib.h in your code.

Add the following preprocessor directives to the top of your code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

You can try to specify where mpi.h is located on your computer as an additional gcc argument, or just place a copy of mpi.h in the same directory you are compiling from.  If you still get this error, then you will need to need to follow the same steps for the mpi.lib or .a file so everything can be linked correctly.  This would be an example of linking with gcc where mpi is in the user/local/lib path.

```
gcc  <normal options>  -L/usr/local/lib/mpi -lmpi
```

Here's a tutorial with different [gcc compiler examples](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/014) that may help too.

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier, you need to

`#include <mpi.h>`

Also, the most "natural" way of building a MPI application is to use the MPI wrappers.
In your case, replace `gcc` with `mpicc` and you won't have to worry of manually adding include/library pathes and linking with the required libraries (which is MPI implementation dependent fwiw)